Cant schedule saturday delivery with FedEx ship api
When scheduling a delivery with FedEx ship api, I can schedule express shipments, but cant figure out how to add Saturday delivery. The documentation FedEx supplies mentions that its possible, but shows no examples or methods to do so.
I am still in the testing environment. Provided is my attempt to schedule a Saturday delivery. I have replaced some personal info, and left commented attempts as well. Here is the link I'm posting this to: https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/ship/v1/shipments  Thank you!
{
  "labelResponseOptions": "URL_ONLY",
  "requestedShipment": {
    "shipper": {
      "contact": {
        "personName": "John Smith",
        "phoneNumber": 1234567890,
        "companyName": "Company1"
      },
      "address": {
        "streetLines": [
          "street road"
        ],
        "city": "ST PETERS",
        "stateOrProvinceCode": "MO",
        "postalCode": 63376,
        "countryCode": "US"
      }
    },
    "recipients": [
      {
        "contact": {
          "personName": "Jane Doe",
          "phoneNumber": 1234567890,
          "companyName": "Recipient Company Name"
        },
        "address": {
          "streetLines": [
            "14228 Schleisman Rd"
          ],
          "city": "Eastvale",
          "stateOrProvinceCode": "CA",
          "postalCode": 92880,
          "countryCode": "US"
        }
      }
    ],
    "shipDatestamp": "2024-05-10",
    "serviceType": "PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT",
    "packagingType": "FEDEX_BOX",
 //   "PackageSpecialServices": {
   //     "specialServiceTypes": [
     //   "SATURDAY_DELIVERY"
       // ]
  //  },
    "pickupType": "USE_SCHEDULED_PICKUP",
    "blockInsightVisibility": false,
    "shippingChargesPayment": {
      "paymentType": "SENDER"
    },


    "labelSpecification": {
      "imageType": "PDF",
      "labelStockType": "PAPER_85X11_TOP_HALF_LABEL"
    },
    "requestedPackageLineItems": [
      {
  
        "customerReferences": [
            {
                "customerReferenceType": "INVOICE_NUMBER",
                "value": "3686"
            },
            
            {
                "customerReferenceType": "P_O_NUMBER",
                "value": "3686"
            }
        ],

        "weight": {
          "value": 10,
          "units": "LB"
        },
        "packageSpecialServices": {
            "specialServiceTypes": [
                "SATURDAY_DELIVERY"
            ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "accountNumber": {
    "value": "xxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}


This is the solution that I found.
"shipDatestamp": "2024-05-10",
"serviceType": "PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT",
"packagingType": "FEDEX_BOX",
"shipmentSpecialServices": {
    "specialServiceTypes": [
        "SATURDAY_DELIVERY"
    ]
},

